# ruby gets 'enter key'

Tags: ruby

How can I recognise input of the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key? The following code won't work for me

```
puts 'press the enter key'
names = gets

if names == '\n'
    puts 'yay'
end
```

Comment: I like using `names = gets.chomp`. It strips the trailing `"\n"` which you'll probably want to do anyway, and makes your test be `if names.empty?`

Comment: @Greg I definitely agree with using `names = gets.chomp` and `if names.empty?`. It is also equivalent to `if names == ""` for those who may wonder.

Comment: `.empty?` is the way to go!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This doesn't work because '\n' looks for the characters, \n instead of a new line. You want to use "\n" so it will actually read it as a newline instead of actual characters.

```
if names == "\n"
    puts "yay"
end
```